# PHP MYSQL import CSV and then compare and remove redundant entries

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, compare

I am stuck with a peculiar issue here. I have a script that basically imports a CSV file into a database using `fgetcsv()` in php. There is no problem in doing this at all and I am able to update old entries as well using MySQL syntax `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (I am in no way a MySQL expert, hence me asking here).

Here is that part of the code:

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");//skip first row since they are headers
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) //read line by line into $fileop
{
  //read array values into vars
  $item1 = $fileop[0];
  $item2 = $fileop[1];
  $key = $fileop[2];
  // and a couple more

  // now INSERT / UPDATE data in MySQL table
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (item1,item2,key) 
    VALUES ('$item1','$item2','$key') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item1='$item1',item2='$item2'");

}
```

This all works fine. What I am stuck with is the fact that some entries may have been removed from the actual CSV (as in the key may no longer be existant). What I would like to do is remove the entries from the MySQL table that are no longer present in the CSV.

Meaning if `$key` is gone from CSV also remove that row in the database table. I suppose I would do it before I run the Insert / Update query on the MySQL table?

I would appreciate any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep an account of your keys.

Save every `$key` in an array in your while, and in the end run a query that says

```
DELETE FROM tabel WHERE key NOT IN (listofcommaseparatedkeysgoeshere)
```

---

```
$arrayThatYouNeedToTest = array();
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");//skip first row since they are headers
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) //read line by line into $fileop
{
  //read array values into vars
  $item1 = $fileop[0];
  $item2 = $fileop[1];
  $key = $fileop[2];
  // and a couple more

  // now INSERT / UPDATE data in MySQL table
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (item1,item2,key) 
    VALUES ('$item1','$item2','$key') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item1='$item1',item2='$item2'");

   $arrayThatYouNeedToTest[] = $key;    

}

$stringThatYouNeedToInspect = implode(",",$arrayThatYouNeedToTest);
$queryYouREALLYneedToCheckFirst = "DELETE FROM tabel WHERE key NOT IN  (".$stringThatYouNeedToInspect.")";

//$result = mysql_query($queryYouREALLYneedToCheckFirst);
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind your thought. Could you iterate a little more and show me how that code would look like? I am new to php and writing expansive code like this, is kind of new to me.

Comment: Well, it should not be that hard, so i'm hesitant to just give you the codes because you might just cut & paste it, and I have no real testing method and/or time right now. but a quick one. BE ADVISED. You should use it to understand what should happen, not copy it!

Comment: Thanks! I dont want to copy/paste I would like to get a deeper understanding of it. I have learned everything that I know thus far from looking at syntax descriptions and examples that people have put out there. The easiest way for myself to learn is by doing / looking at examples and then replica and extend on what I have learned.

Comment: By coincidence I was just looking at syntax of imploding an array while you put the code here :) I'll get to work, great stuff and thanks a million.

Comment: no problem, just make sure do some `echo` // `var_dump` checks before putting it in the DELETE, as you don't want to remove all

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar to this with an affiliate website - having just under 500,000 products.

In your database, simply add another column named "update_flag" or something similar. Set the default to be 0. As you add items from the CSV file, set the update_flag to be "1". In your 'on duplicate statement', set the filed to be "2". I also went and added 2 other fields: "date_added" and "date_updated".

After your import is complete, you can count the old items (to be deleted), newly added items, and those that have been updated. You can then simple delete from table where update_flag = 0

I hope this helps.