# Modify database value if a different vaule matches a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

Ok, I am new here and if my question has already been answered, please direct me, but I cannot find it.

I have a database with products in it. I receive a list of product codes from my supplier in a csv format. It has only 1 column. I want to take that list of product codes and compare to the list of codes in my database. If a product code is on the list in the csv, I want to modify a stock status value for that product in the database. so basically,

if "item_a" exists, change "value_b".

I hope I have been clear enough to get the correct answer...

Thank you in advance.

P.S. This>>[PHP MYSQL import CSV and then compare and remove redundant entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872551/php-mysql-import-csv-and-then-compare-and-remove-redundant-entries)
seems to be in the right direction, however instead of deleting, I  want to change a different value

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: mass amounts of googling. I have no idea where to even begin...

Comment: I am hoping that I can create some kind of basic CRUD that will collect all of the csv values into an array and compare them to the existing data. I have very little coding experience and am trying to start an estore...

Comment: @EdwardLane use the fgetcsv function and get the data from CSV. You need to write some methods to search the data against the DB and update the DB respectively. If you already using any framework or CMS, use their native methods for search and update request.

Comment: I don't think I have enough server memory from my host to allow for that much data, the csv and the entire database, to be run against one another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store all the csv data in an array then use this:-

```
foreach($csvId as $productID){
$productID = mysql_real_escape_string($productID);
$res = mysql_query('select count(*) from products where product_id = ' .$productID) or die();
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    //productexists
$updated_result = mysql_query('UPDATE products SET product.item_a="value_b" where product_id = ' .$productID) or die();
    }
else
{
    //It doesn't
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I believe that I have figured out the answers to my questions by reading and rereading the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can user php function fgetcsv() get colum, than strcmp() compare diff value update.

[>> fgetcsv()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp)

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like I would have to have all of my data in the same order...

[value1]=>[value3] = 0
[value2]=>[value4] = 0
[value3]=>[value5] = 0

right?